# How to pass an Image from UserControl1 to another UserControl2 (C#, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have 2 UserControls on my Form1. They are stacked on top each other within a panel. In UserControl1 i load the image from a file using the OpenFileDialog. On my Form1 i have also a Toggle Button, where the user can switch between the two UserControls. This works pretty well, but how can I pass the image from UserControl1 (contains image on panel)  to UserControl2 (contains pictureBox control for displaying the image) as soon as the Toggle Button is set to the state - toggle button is checked ? Thanks for any hint !

**UserControl1**

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {        
        private static UserControl1 _instance;
        public static UserControl1 Instance
        {
          get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new UserControl1();

                return _instance;
            }
        }

        private Image _icon;
        public Image Icon
        {
            get { return _icon; }
            set { _icon = value; panel1.BackgroundImage = value; }
        }

        private void OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog())
                {
                    OFD.Filter = "Picture Files|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png;*.tif";

                    if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {                    
                        panel1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(OFD.FileName);                                         
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**UserControl2**

```
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static UserControl2 _instance;
        public static UserControl2 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                    _instance = new UserControl2();
                return _instance;
            }
        }
```

**Form1**

```
private void ToggleButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            
   if (!toggleButton1.Checked)
   {
      if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl1.Instance))
      {
          panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl1.Instance);
          UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
      }
      else
      {
         UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();                       
      }

   }

   if (toggleButton1.Checked)
   {
      if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl2.Instance))
      {
          panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl2.Instance);
          UserControl2.Instance.BringToFront();                      
      }
      else
      {
         UserControl2.Instance.BringToFront();                        
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you forgot to give UserControl2 an Icon property as well.

Comment: Why not just have a property on user control 2 that receives an Image, then set it when you toggle? In essence, if your question was "how do I take the text showing in a TextBox and put it in a RichTextBox when I click a button?", you'd code up a button click that did `myRich.Text = myText.Text`; this doesn't really seem any difference?

Comment: I just managed it. The UserControls can be stacked on top each other. All i had to do was to create a button on my form: private void Mb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { using( Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap (userControl1.panel1.ClientSize.Width, userControl1.panel1.ClientSize.Height)){ try{ userControl1.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, userControl1.panel1.ClientRectangle);  userControl2.pictureBox1.Image = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(0,0,bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height), PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb); } catch (Exception){}}}

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, "Caius Jard"